# Creating a values only copy of an excel workbook without opening it

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I have created a working VBA script that allows the user to select a workbook and make a values only copy of it without opening it. This is useful for getting data from a workbook that is very slow to open. From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398348/how-can-i-copy-the-values-only-from-an-entire-excel-workbook-without-opening-it/

I can very quickly make a values only copy of an entire workbook. The result is a fast, lightweight, usable workbook that only contains values from the original workbook.

I want to know if there are ways I can/should improve what I have done.

I also want to know if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result.

Main Sub

```
Public Sub Copy_Workbook_Values_Only()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim intCount    As Integer
    Dim firstSheet  As Boolean
    Dim sheetname   As String
    Dim trimmedname As String
    
    Dim db          As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rsSheet = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim wbnew       As Workbook
    
    ExcelFileFullPath = PickFile()
    If ExcelFileFullPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim strcon      As String
    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & ExcelFileFullPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;"""
    db.Open (strcon)
    
    Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)        'should make just one sheet in new workbook
    firstSheet = True
    
    Set rs = db.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "Table"))
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        sheetname = rs!TABLE_NAME
        
        'must be a better way to get only sheets
        'ADO filter does not support "ends with"
        'I would like a way to either return only sheets (no named ranges) or filter for the same
        'currently just check to see if last character is a $
        If IsNotWorksheet(sheetname) Then GoTo NextIteration
        
        'get rid of any illegal or extra characters added to worksheet name
        trimmedname = Sanitize_Worksheet_Name(sheetname)
        
        If firstSheet Then
            Set currentSheet = wbnew.Sheets(1)
            firstSheet = False
        Else
            If WorksheetExists(trimmedname) Then GoTo NextIteration        'skip if name somehow already exists
            Set currentSheet = wbnew.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
        End If
        
        currentSheet.name = trimmedname
        
        'get data and write to worksheet
        SQLCompound = "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetname & "]"
        rsSheet.Open SQLCompound, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
        currentSheet.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rsSheet
        rsSheet.Close
        
NextIteration:
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    If Not db Is Nothing Then
        If db.State = adStateOpen Then db.Close
    End If
    Set db = Nothing
    
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Source & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Helper Functions:

```
Private Function PickFile() As String
    ' Create and set the file dialog object.
    Dim fd          As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    Set objSFolders = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders
    
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear        ' Clear all the filters (if applied before).
        
        ' Give the dialog box a title, word for doc or Excel for excel files.
        .Title = "Select an Excel File"
        
        ' Apply filter to show only a particular type of files.
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", 1
        .Filters.Add "All Excel Files", "*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr", 2
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 3
        
        ' Do not allow users to select more than one file.
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
        .InitialFileName = objSFolders("mydocuments")
        
        ' Show the file.
        If .Show = True Then
            PickFile = .SelectedItems(1)        ' Get the complete file path.
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

```
Private Function Sanitize_Worksheet_Name(sheetname As String) As String
    
    result = sheetname
    If Left(result, 1) = Chr(39) And Right(result, 1) = Chr(39) Then        'name has been wrapped in single quotes
    result = Mid(result, 2, Len(result) - 2)
End If

If Right(result, 1) = "$" Then        'remove trailing $
result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End If

'Sheet tab names cannot contain the characters /, \, [, ], *, ?, or :.
Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer
IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"
For i = 1 To 7
    result = Replace(result, IllegalCharacter(i), "")
Next i

result = Left(result, 31)        'no more than 31 chars

Sanitize_Worksheet_Name = result
End Function
```

```
Private Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
    
End Function
```

```
'probably a better way for checking for this
'sheetnames from database end in $, but may have a trailing quote after
'tables/named ranges cannot have $ in their name in excel
'tables/named ranges will only have an interior $ -- after the sheetname, but before the range name
Private Function IsNotWorksheet(sheetname As String) As Boolean
    i = 0
    If Right(sheetname, 1) = Chr(39) Then i = 1        'ignore trailing single quote
    If Mid(sheetname, Len(sheetname) - i, 1) <> "$" Then        'not a sheet
    IsNotWorksheet = True
Else
    IsNotWorksheet = False
End If
End Function
```

Here is a link to the pertinent post about not being able to use an "ends with" filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632420/vba-recordset-filter-wildcard-ending-with-not-working-error-3001

Answer (score 2):

I was able to greatly simplify the code using `ADOX.Catalog` to pull sheets instead of trying to figure out what is or is not a sheet. I also added code that will allow you to open any type of Excel file and always have the correct SQL connection string.

I have some general notes here for you:

- Use RubberDuck to format your code and help you review
- Never use underscore "_" in procedure name because those are reserved for VBA events.
- Only one declaration per `Dim`
- Use Late-bound objects for code portablility
- Use `Option Explicit` to force you to declare all your variables
- Don't use `Goto` when you can use `If`

Here is my version of the code:

```
Option Explicit

' Set all external enums for late bound compatibility
Const adOpenStatic As Long = 3
Const adLockReadOnly As Long = 1
Const adCmdText As Long = 1
Const adStateOpen As Long = 1

Public Sub CopyWorkbookValuesOnly()
    ' Handle requirements first
    Dim excelFileFullPath As String
    excelFileFullPath = PickFile
    
    If excelFileFullPath = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim excelDB          As Object
    Set excelDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    excelDB.Open GetConnectionString(excelFileFullPath)
    
    Dim wbnew       As Workbook
    Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)   'should make just one sheet in new workbook

    ' Get all the Sheets
    Dim sheetTabs As Object
    With CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
        .ActiveConnection = excelDB
        Set sheetTabs = .Tables
    End With
    
    Dim firstSheet As Boolean
    firstSheet = True
    Dim tableSheet As Object
    For Each tableSheet In sheetTabs
        Dim trimmedname As String
        If Left$(tableSheet.Name, 1) = Chr$(39) And Right$(tableSheet.Name, 1) = Chr$(39) Then ' the name has been wrapped in single quotes
            trimmedname = Mid$(tableSheet.Name, 2, Len(tableSheet.Name) - 2)
        Else ' start with just the name
            trimmedname = tableSheet.Name
        End If
        
        If Right$(trimmedname, 1) = "$" Then
            trimmedname = SanitizeWorksheetName(trimmedname)
            Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
            If firstSheet Then
                Set currentSheet = wbnew.Sheets(1)
                firstSheet = False
            Else
                Set currentSheet = wbnew.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
            End If
            
            currentSheet.Name = trimmedname
            
            'get data and write to worksheet
            Dim sqlCompound As String
            sqlCompound = "SELECT * FROM [" & tableSheet.Name & "]"
            
            Dim rsSheet As Object
            Set rsSheet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            rsSheet.Open sqlCompound, excelDB, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
            currentSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsSheet
            rsSheet.Close
            Set rsSheet = Nothing
        End If
    Next tableSheet
      
ErrorHandler:
    If Not excelDB Is Nothing Then
        If excelDB.State = adStateOpen Then excelDB.Close
        Set excelDB = Nothing
    End If
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Source & "Error number: " & Err.Number & "-->" & Err.Description, , "Error"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function PickFile() As String
    ' Create and set the file dialog object.
    Dim specialFolder As Object
    Set specialFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Clear                           ' Clear all the filters (if applied before).
        
        ' Give the dialog box a title, word for doc or Excel for excel files.
        .Title = "Select an Excel File"
        
        ' Apply filter to show only a particular type of files.
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", 1
        .Filters.Add "All Excel Files", "*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr", 2
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 3
        
        ' Do not allow users to select more than one file.
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
        .InitialFileName = specialFolder("MyDocuments")
        
        ' Show the file.
        If .Show = True Then
            PickFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)         ' Get the complete file path.
        End If
    End With
End Function

Private Function SanitizeWorksheetName(ByVal sheetName As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    result = sheetName

    If Right$(result, 1) = "$" Then               'remove trailing $
        result = Left$(result, Len(result) - 1)
    End If
    
    ' Remove illegal characters using RegEx
    Const IllegalCharacters As String = "\/\\\[\]\*:"
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = IllegalCharacters
        result = .Replace(result, vbNullString)
    End With
    
    ' keep only 31 characters
    SanitizeWorksheetName = Left$(result, 31)
End Function

Public Function GetConnectionString(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Dim fileExtension As String
    fileExtension = Right$(fileName, Len(fileName) - InStrRev(fileName, "."))
    Dim provider As String
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Dim connectionString As String
    Select Case fileExtension
    Case "xls"
        connectionString = provider & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    Case "xlsx"
        connectionString = provider & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    Case "xlsb"
        connectionString = provider & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    Case "xlsm"
        connectionString = provider & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    Case Else
        connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & fileName & ";"
    End Select
    
    GetConnectionString = connectionString
End Function
```

Comment: This code chokes on my original use case - a spreadsheet with (thousands?) of named ranges. It makes a tab for each of the named ranges, not just each of the sheets. Also, if the original workbook contains a Sheet1 it errors out as the new workbook already has a sheet1 and cannot make another by the same name.

Comment: However, I did really appreciate your feedback overall and will incorporate what I can.

Comment: You can only have one sheet named "Sheet1" and it does come with one. The name should be set on each pass so you won't ever have a collision. I've tested that much. I need to test the named ranges. I will have to make an example workbook to see what you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, @S.Melted, please try this latest version. It should ignore named ranges as you expect.

Comment: It now snappily goes through the original workbook with thousands of named ranges. However, I made a worksheet with two tabs named "ab" and "12". It will import "ab" but not "12" because it wraps 12$ in single quotes for the tableSheet.name making the last character a single quote, not a $.

Comment: To copy the sheets correctly, we still need to either set HDR=NO, or go and copy the "header" rows as well. As is, it chops off the first row.

Comment: It  no longer crashes when given a workbook with an existing "Sheet1"

Comment: Ok, I have made edits to account for numeric sheet names. I also used `HDR=NO` to avoid stripping the headers.